# Scala - Flatmap a Seq of Options and Traversable

Tags: scala, flatmap

Consider a flatMap written over some case matching. For example:

```
list.flatMap( v =>
    v match {
        case Cond1 => if(something) Some(Int) else None
        //..Other conditions yielding Option[Int]
        case CondN => if(somethingelse) Seq(Int) else Seq()
    })
```

However this wont compile. If the seq is all of Option[Int] or all of Seq[Int] the flatMap works. But not if the Seq is a mix of Options and Seqs. Why is such a restriction in place? Does this solve a particular ambiguity that I cannot think of as of now.

**EDIT1**
Adding code snippet from REPL

```
scala> val a = Seq(Option(1), Seq(2,3))
a: Seq[Equals] = List(Some(1), List(2, 3))

scala> val b = Seq(Seq(1), Seq(2,3))
b: Seq[Seq[Int]] = List(List(1), List(2, 3))

scala> a.flatMap(x=>x)
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Equals
 required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
              a.flatMap(x=>x)
                           ^

scala> b.flatMap(x=>x)
res24: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

**EDIT2**
After Filippo's answer I tried the following piece of code in the REPL and it worked.

```
scala> val options = Seq("opt1", "opt2")
options: Seq[String] = List(opt1, opt2)

scala> options.flatMap( x => 
     |      x match {
     |      case "opt1" => Some(1)
     |      case "opt2" => Seq(2,3)
     |      case _ => None
     |      })
res27: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

How is the resolution different in each of the scenarios. 
More importantly when I map instead of flatMap the result is the same as the `Seq` a that I had created.

```
scala> options.map( x => 
 |      x match {
 |      case "opt1" => Some(1)
 |      case "opt2" => Seq(2,3)
 |      case _ => None
 |      })
res28: Seq[Equals] = List(Some(1), List(2, 3))
```

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: can you give a working piece of code that we can use in REPL?

Comment: @Jus12 Updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Option` is a `GenTraversableOnce` but scala needs some help here:

```
  val a: Seq[TraversableOnce[Int]] = Seq(Option(1), Seq(2,3))
  a.flatMap(x=>x)

  res0: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

---

**EDIT** after additions to the question

I think that if the type of your sequence is the one you are expecting, everything boils down to the function passed to the flatMap. If scala can't figure out that the function is `(A) => Traversable[A]` when the starting sequence is `Seq[A]`, I think we should make some types explicit.

Now, back to your first sample, I would refactor it as:

```
list.flatMap {
  case Cond1 if something     => Seq(Int)
  case CondN if somethingelse => Seq(Int)
  case _                      => Seq()
}
```

No doubt scala is now able to infer the types correctly.

Comment: I think I asked the wrong question. I did not check it with pattern matching. Before writing my application I was just testing out if such a flatmap works in the REPL and it failed however I generalised it for pattern matching. After your answer I tried it for pattern matching and it does work in that scenario. So how is it able to resolve it in that case and not when we make `Seq` explicitly.

Comment: The actual matching is quite complex. I have created a simplistic example and updated the question.

Comment: `Option` and `Seq` are isomorphic (for sequences of one element), right?

Comment: In a way yes. But then there are differences as well. In this example since all we need is to flatten it perhaps its the same.

Comment: I think I got the point when you said `everything boils down to the function passed to the flatMap`. In the case of passing a function to flatMap scala knows that the resultant must be a TraversableOnce or it tries to cast all possible return types to `TraversableOnce` In case of writing the same function as a standalone since no explicit casting is done by Scala it results in a `Seq[Equals]` Object. Thank you for the explanation. Marking it as correct.